# Eclipse gives undefined reference when calling a function in another c file

Tags: c, linux, function, include, real-time

Im using eclipse for Linux mealtime system as target, and coding with C programming.

I  made a c file (digital.c) and it has some functions inside it, when i try to call that function form my main. it says un-defined reference to that function

should i include the c file like include?

how can i call a function in some other file from my main.

I have already included the path of that c file in GCC compiler include paths.

Comment: Show your compilation statement.

Comment: Only having them in include path with not suffice, you need to compile and link them together to form the binary.

Comment: Can  you help me do that?

Answer (score 0):

If your main file is main.cpp and the function is in file test.cpp :

```
 g++ main.cpp test.cpp
```

Comment: im using c programing

Comment: You can also use gcc instead of g++.